# Using php to select with prepared statement and echoing the result or turning it into variable

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm working on a localhost project. Even though I might not need it, but while learning php and mysql I figured I should use prepared statements. I'm not quite getting through with it even though I've found some great guides online.

What I'm looking for is simply to echo the name from my database. Later on I'd need to turn it into variable, but since I'm already stuck with this, I figured I'd ask here.

```
require_once "config.php";

if ($link->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT name FROM users")) {
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($name);

    while ($stmt->fetch()) {
        echo ("$name");
    }
    $stmt->close();
}
$mysqli->close();
```

Comment: _Small Note_ There is little point preparing a query that has no bindable parameters.

Comment: To get errors out of PHP even in a LIVE environment add these 4 lines to the top of any `MYSQLI_` based script you want to debug 
`ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('log_errors',1); error_reporting(E_ALL); mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);`. 
This will force any `MYSQLI_` errors to generate an Exception that you can see on the browser as well as normal PHP errors.

Comment: if you show us the config.php then it will better to understand.

Comment: Thank you! For testing purposes I did not bind parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this line is correct

```
if ($link->connect_error) {
```

then this line is WRONG

```
if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT name FROM users")) {
```

and this statement is also WRONG

```
$conn->connect_error
```

as the connection variable is either `$link` or `$mysqli` or `$conn` but it is unlikely to be all og them!

> Or maybe both are wrong. The answer will be in the code you didn't show us in `config.php`, so check what variable you used in that script.

Comment: You missed `$conn->connect_error`. There are 3 of them.

Comment: Thank you! I totally missed that, I probably mixed it up with my previous code. This solved my case :)